# F# set value of function

Tags: f#

I have three functions in a module, SetBehaviour that calls GetBehviour which reads a text file and deserialize it back to my types and return it back to useCases. I then gain acess to the object I want by 'let behavior = useCases.Item(useCaseIdentifier)'

My question is there a way to set 'GlobalBehavior' to the return value of 'SetBehaviour' so i can call 'GlobalBehaviour' directly without going through the reading of the text file and deserialization every time?

```
let GlobalBehaviour = //The return value of SetBehaviour here


let GetBehaviour =
    let useCases = Data.ReadUseCases
    let deserializedUseCases = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Map<string,Types.UseCase>>(useCases)
    deserializedUseCases


let SetBehaviour useCaseIdentifier =
    let useCases = GetBehaviour
    let behavior = useCases.Item(useCaseIdentifier)
    behavior
```

Comment: Are you trying to cache the result once the function is called? Or do you just want to initialize the value to some "default" when the application loads?

Comment: Do you want SetBehavior to remember what has been read from the text file? On a side note, why isn't `SetBehavior` named something more aptly like `GetUsecaseById`?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to cache to result of SetBehaviour in GlobalBehaviour. So i can call Module.GlobalBehaviour from another module.

Comment: Hi Christian, this is a work in progress but yes thats a far better name for that function.

Comment: @AlanMulligan doesn't `GlobalBehavior` lack a parameter since it should call `SetBehavior`, `useCaseIdentifier` that is?

Comment: No, GlobalBehaviour should be able to be called with out any parameters. GlobalBehaviour will only be called in other modules which wont know anything about any of the parameters needed..

Comment: @AlanMulligan So which value will you pass to `SetBehavior` when called from `GlobalBehavior`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99482/discussion-between-alan-mulligan-and-christian).

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends a lot on the context. For example is this some initialization that happens only once, or is it something that changes frequently?

In general, it is better to avoid global mutable state in F# and instead remember the last behaviour somewhere in the module that accesses the module you are showing in your question. That way, the client is in control of the state (and there are various ways to make that nicer). Also, if you were writing a concurrent system, it might make sense to use an agent instead.

However, the basic solution using mutation would look something like this:

```
let mutable GlobalBehaviour = None // Initially the global behaviour is not set

let SetBehaviour useCaseIdentifier =
    let useCases = GetBehaviour
    let behavior = useCases.Item(useCaseIdentifier)
    GlobalBehaviour <- Some behaviour // Now we set it to the last one
    behaviour
```

In practice, it might make more sense to use some other approach. For example, if you want to run this just once, you could use a `lazy` value (which evaluates a function once and caches the result, so that your configuration is not read repeatedly). But it's hard to give a better answer without more details.

Answer (score 2):

You could cache the use cases read from file at module initialization like so:

```
module UseCaseModule
let GlobalBehaviour = //Retreive use case from cachedUseCases and useCaseId
let private cachedUseCases = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Map<string,Types.UseCase>>(Data.ReadUseCases)
let mutable private useCaseId = None
let private SetBehaviour useCaseIdentifier =
   useCaseId <- useCaseIdentifier
```